# How to host ASP.NET Core 2.0 (Kestrel) with Unix domain socket behind a nginx proxy?

Tags: nginx, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am current using ASP.NET Core 2.0 behind nginx through HTTP requests in Ubuntu 16.

And I'd like to switch to Unix domain socket.

In my **Program.cs** I have:

```cs
var host = default(IWebHost);
var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel(opt =>
    {
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux) && settings.Config.ListenUnixSocket)
        {
            opt.ListenUnixSocket("/tmp/api.sock");
        }
    })
    .Configure(app =>
    {
        app.Map("/health", b => b.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Ok");
        }));
    });

if(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) || !settings.Config.ListenUnixSocket)
{
    host = builder.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5501").Build();
}
else
{
    host = builder.Build();
}

host.Run();
```

And, at **Nginx**:

```txt
location /health {
  #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5501;
  proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/api.sock:/;
}
```

Running it using the default TCP socket works, but switching to Unix domain sockets, I got a 502 error.

Do I need any specific module at nginx? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aspnetcore will create api.socket when its running but Nginx must have permission to write.

So, if you don't know what user nginx uses, execute:

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

You'll get something this in the terminal:

```
root      5005  0.0  0.2 125116  1460 ?        Ss   20:12   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data  5006  0.0  0.6 125440  3260 ?        S    20:12   0:00 nginx: worker process
root      5173  0.0  0.1  14516   920 pts/0    S+   20:17   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Then you set the permission:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /tmp/api.sock
```

And, that's it!

Answer (score 0):

@Apolineo correctly identified that the Unix socket's permissions need to be opened up to allow other users to connect to the socket.

However, a better solution than manually setting the permissions is to do it programmatically from Main immediately after the socket is created.

Example solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60272454/51055).